# return only false values in SQL

Tags: sql

How do I modify this to return only false values and avoid true values

```
SELECT b."/BIC/ZSORHDR",
case when a."/BIC/ZSORHDR" is null then 'false' else end
FROM sappha."/BIC/ADD060400"  b
LEFT OUTER JOIN sappha."/BIC/AOPM20400" a
ON (b."/BIC/ZSORHDR" = a."/BIC/ZSORHDR")
WHERE  b."LOAD_DATE" = '20210118'
```

Comment: What is your database ? Is it MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer... ?

Comment: you can try to add to your query   ..AND a."/BIC/ZSORHDR" is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic in the `CASE` expression in the select to the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT b."/BIC/ZSORHDR"
FROM sappha."/BIC/ADD060400" b
LEFT JOIN sappha."/BIC/AOPM20400" a
    ON b."/BIC/ZSORHDR" = a."/BIC/ZSORHDR"
WHERE
    b."LOAD_DATE" = '20210118' AND
    a."/BIC/ZSORHDR" IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT b."/BIC/ZSORHDR"
  FROM sappha."/BIC/ADD060400"  b
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (select 1 from sappha."/BIC/AOPM20400" a
        WHERE b."/BIC/ZSORHDR" = a."/BIC/ZSORHDR")
  AND b."LOAD_DATE" = '20210118'
```